# how to group, group_concat in table with two joins

Tags: mysql

At the moment I have one table for products, one for prices and one for toppings, and I am using the following code to build my JSON file

```
SELECT `products`.`PrID` as `id`, `name`, group_concat(product_prices.size)as sizes, group_concat(product_prices.price)as prices, group_concat(product_toppings.IID)as IIDs
FROM `products`
JOIN `product_prices` ON `product_prices`.`PrID` = `products`.`PrID`
JOIN `product_toppings` ON `product_toppings`.`PrID` = `products`.`PrID`
WHERE `products`.`PrID` = '2'
AND `products`.`status` = 'active'
GROUP BY `products`.`PrID`
```

My current result:

```
{"id":"2","name":"Hawaiian","sizes":"medium,medium,medium,medium,large,large,large,large,supersize,supersize,supersize,supersize","prices":"11.99,11.99,11.99,11.99,14.99,14.99,14.99,14.99,16.99,16.99,16.99,16.99","IIDs":"7,18,22,28,7,18,22,28,7,18,22,28"}
```

I know my issue is with grouping but I cant figure out how to group it best so i get something like:

```
{"id":"2","name":"name","sizes":"medium,large,large,supersize","prices":"11.99,14.99,16.99","IIDs":"7,18,22,28"}
```

Comment: `group_concat(distinct product_prices.size order by product_prices.size)` and same for prices.

Comment: that just solved my problem, thank you so much